# Pass variable from server to a webpack bundle on response

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have an application which is being served from a simple express server, currently it is serving the same `app.bundle.js` for every single request it receives.

Within my application, I want to create varying behaviour based on some of the request parameters, for example based on the Geography of the user as passed in a header by nginx or maybe by parsing the querystring.

As the bundle is static - I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Ideally, when sending the bundle - I can pass along an javascript object.

Comment: Maybe add another script tag with with the data you need to provide?

Comment: The data comes from the server, so feels messy.